# Share Contract in Metro app

Tags: windows-8

I am writing a metro app using javascript and HTML that implements the Share Contract. I want the users of my app to post data to Social networking sites like Facebook. I have configured the People app in my system, but i am not getting it(People app option) in the share pane in the charms bar. I am seeing the People app option  in other apps that i have downloaded from the store.Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

People app of Windows 8 Release Preview supports only Share Link.
People App of Windows 8 RTM Supports both Text & Link Sharing.

To Share Text:

```
request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Text Example";
//Description is Optional
request.Data.Properties.Description = "A demonstration that shows how to share text.";
request.Data.SetText("Hello World!");
```

To Share link:

```
request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Link Example";
//Description is Optional
request.Data.Properties.Description = "Demonstrates how to add a link (URI) to share.";
request.Data.SetUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Which apps that show up in the Share list are determined by what types of data you are sharing.  Each target app informs Windows 8 what data types it is capable of accepting. Windows will only show those apps that support the data types being shared from the source application. For example, if I only share plain text on a clean install system

```
request.data.setText("some plain text to share");
```

I will only see the Mail app show up.

However, if I also share a URI, I will now see both the Mail and the People app show up.

```
request.data.setText("some plain text to share");
request.data.setUri(new Uri("http://slickthought.net"));
```

I suspect that whatever set*() calls you are making are not one of the data type's that the People app supports.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff.. Is there a way to find the type of data expected by the target app ?